# Set port ldap php

Tags: php, ldap

Currently I have this piece of code:

```
<?php

function authenticate($user, $password) {
    if(empty($user) || empty($password)) return false;

    // active directory server
    $ldap_host = "ldaps.test.nl";
    $ldap_port = "389";

    // active directory DN (base location of ldap search)
    $ldap_dn = "OU=Users,OU=test users & Groups,DC=test,DC=nl";

    // active directory user group name
    $ldap_user_group = "Users";

    // active directory manager group name
    $ldap_manager_group = "IT_Inventory";

    // domain, for purposes of constructing $user
    $ldap_usr_dom = '@test.nl';

    // connect to active directory
    $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

    // configure ldap params
    ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);

    // verify user and password
    if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
        // valid
        // check presence in groups
        $filter = "(sAMAccountName=".$user.")";
        $attr = array("memberof");
        $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        ldap_unbind($ldap);

        // check groups
        $access = 0;
        foreach($entries[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {
            // is manager, break loop
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_manager_group)) { $access = 2; break; }

            // is user
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_user_group)) $access = 1;
        }

        if($access != 0) {
            // establish session variables
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
            return true;
        } else {
            // user has no rights
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        // invalid name or password
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

What I want to do is in the ldap connect specify the port.
I already have done so by trying this:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host,$ldap_port);
```

How can I specify the port in the ldap connect normally it works fine on ldaps.test.nl but now the certificate has passed and we need another one this takes a litte while so I need to bypass the ldaps and just use ldap by changing the port.

Hope someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `ldap_connect($host, $port)` the protocol will **always** be plain `ldap`. To use `ldaps` you need to call `ldap_connect` with an LDAP-URI. So in your case that would be `ldaps://ldaps.test.nl:389`.

As you are using insecure ldap at the moment anyhow (389 is the default LDAP-Port and the way you call `ldap_connect` **can not** make a secure connection) I'm not exactly sure what the underlying problem is. Because you are already using an insecure connection. For more info have a look at the documentation at https://www.php.net/ldap_connect

Have you had a look whether the LDAP-Connection is created via an already existing SSL/TLS-Tunnel that can't be created due to the outdated certificate? Then you would need to close that tunnel. But that seems not to be aprt of the PHP-Script so is configured elsewhere.

For the future I'd advise to use `ldap_connect` with an URI in any case. And then either use `ldaps` as protocol or use [`ldap_start_tls`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php) to immediately start a secure connection after initializing the connection.